# Wordpress wp-post-image class remover

Tags: wordpress

We use `the_post_thumbnails` to get our images displayed.

We want to use them with a specific class called "test" but we cant manage it!

We use this code:

```
 <?php the_post_thumbnail('pin-photo-large', array('class' => 'test')); ?>
```

But the output of the image seems like this:

```
 class="test wp-post-image"
```

How can we overcome this issue and get an output like this ?

```
 class="test"
```

Comment: Why is it a problem to have `wp-post-image` in there additionally?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Add this to your `functions.php` file:

```
remove_action( 'begin_fetch_post_thumbnail_html', '_wp_post_thumbnail_class_filter_add' );
```

Explanation: In `media.php`, the `_wp_post_thumbnail_class_filter` function adds the `wp-post-image` class to post thumbnails. By removing the `begin_fetch_post_thumbnail_html` action hook (located in `default-filters.php`), the function will no longer apply to `the_post_thumbnail`.

---

**Old answer below:**

I also searched for a proper way to filter out the `wp-post-image` class, alas to no avail. The only solution I figured out was to edit a (*gasp!*) core file: `media.php` and replace this:

```
function _wp_post_thumbnail_class_filter( $attr ) {
    $attr['class'] .= ' wp-post-image';
    return $attr;
}
```

by this:

```
function _wp_post_thumbnail_class_filter( $attr ) {
    return $attr;
}
```

There's certainly a better way to do this than to patch a core file, but this can be a good temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `functions.php` file :

```
function remove_post_image_class($content) {
    $post_string = $content;
    $post_string = preg_replace('/<img class=".*?"/', '<img', $post_string);
    return $post_string;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_post_image_class' );
```

Enjoy