# HTML newsletter image scaling

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to finish development on an HTML newsletter.
The HTML is already responsive and working.

When trying to scale the images retrieved from WordPress posts via the_post_thumbnail, i have to use the following nonsensical code to make it work:

`<img class="img_scale" <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(285,400));?>`

as opposed to it's correct form:

`<?php the_post_thumbnail(array (285,400), array('class' => 'img_scale')); ?>`

1. How is it possible the first line of code actually works ?
2. How come the second line of code does not work ?

Comment: This is possible because the the_post_thumbnail already outputs the tag <img>.
When you call the the_post_thumbnail within a tag <img> it ends encapsulating one tag inside another, which returns the wrong browser.

Comment: Solved, found my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863391/wordpress-wp-post-image-class-remover